# Can I splice a chandelier cord to reach a junction box?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I purchased a Arteriors' Geoffrey chandelier. Unfortunately, when I got it home I realized that the chain and wire are not long enough to hang from our 14' ceiling.  I called an electrician to install it and he told me I would have to have the fixture's wiring completely replaced before they would install.

Is there a reason why I cannot purchase additional wire and chain and extend?  The printing on the wire:

```
(UL) E309953 SPT-2 2x1.31mm (16AWG) 105oC 300V VW-1 FT2 TOONG YEAN HSF
```

There is also a ground wire separate from this that runs to the fixture.

Comment: Is replacing the existing cordage on the fixture with a longer length not an option?

Comment: Can you post photos of the fixture in question, even?

Comment: Please [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because splices that are not in boxes are not code compliant.

An electrician can lose his license for installing devices that do not meet code.

So it can’t be done done by a licensed professional with a splice in the wire outside a box.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. My Father and I rewired a cottage so I am comfortable with electrical work. I totally understand since it is not code, an electrician cannot perform the work. I traced the wiring back to the fixture, and it would be a major project to get the fixture rewired so that the wire would be one going from fixture to junction box. If I were to purchase the same wire & ground wire, can this be done safely, or is there a risk. If I can't do this, I probably wasted $1,300 on a fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a small "box" in which the splice could be contained and which would hang onto the chain? Something like one of those [very small inline switches](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EOQO8PS) that fits in a lamp cord. It might even be disguised as a design element.

What about fitting a [line plug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007QVW3MO) to the end of the wire from to the end of the cord from the fixture and a line receptacle to the cord going to the ceiling box?

Or a [project junction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F3X2ZZ9)?